# (Html and css) had a issue with setting a background image in the wrapper

Tags: css, html

I`m new to web designing, had a small problem with setting a background image in the wrapper. Please be kind enough to go through the following source codes and css files. Your assitance will be highly appreciated.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: The `div`'s height is `0px` because it's fit to its content, which is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `height` as well.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```